# Automating "load more" button pressing

Tags: web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a page and I have all the code set, just that I got stuck on the "load more" button. The page is simple, it has items, but only a few. On a web browser to view the rest of the items you would click on a html button which has an onClick event, when it is pressed, more items are loaded and so on until all of them are on the page, then it disappears. As of now I send a request and store it in a variable, the have BeautifulSoup parse it. How would I go about loading the rest of the items into that variable? Should I be taking a different approach?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to take different approach. Let me explain why.

"Load more" button usually triggers new request to site's API. Then JS code renders received data into page You're watching. BS is not an option to control such cases - You have to implement walking logic by yourself.

You have two approaches in this case:

1. Use scraper (or write code), that can evaluate js-code (webdrivers like selenium, puppeteer, etc) and create script for walking and crawling resulting DOM;
2. Investigate API, that is being used by "load more" button. If this API transparent and easy to use - it is usually possible to crawl all needed data via it (only with requests module).